# What prefix to use for methods that create or calculate a value

Tags: oop, coding-style, naming-conventions

I wonder what prefix you guys use for methods that create or calculate a value based on given parameters. I tend to use "get", but that feels wrong, because it looks like a getter then.
For methods that fetch from the database I use "fetch", but for methods that create a value based on the given input I haven't found a satisfying prefix yet. ("create" feels a bit too generic). Are there guidelines for this or is everyone just thinking up something for themselves?

Pseudo code example:

```
class myClass
{
    method getOrderFlowpoint(par1, par2, par3) {
        // do stuff based on the parameters
        return orderFlowpoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to not use prefixes. I tend to name the method according to the exact function it fulfills.

If your function calculates the order flowpoint, that's exactly how you should name it. `calculateOrderFlowpoint`.

Comment: Not the answers I was hoping for, but this comes closest to an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is only about OrderFlowPoints, I have seen the following, all linked to the Factory Pattern:

```
OrderFlowPoint.of(par1, par2, par3);
OrderFlowPoint.valueOf(par1, par2, par3);
OrderFlowPoint.newInstance(par1, par2, par3);
```

Comment: nice suggestions. I will definetely take it into consideration!